# PostgreSQL subselect row as function param

Tags: postgresql, subquery

**I want to pass the result of a subselect to a function**

Say I've got an existing function that returns `boolean`

function `report_can_edit` which takes a `report` row type.  I want to call this from another function which is passed an `id` for a `report`

( just a silly example to illustrate what I'm trying to do )

```
create or replace function report_can_edit(report report) returns boolean as $$
  select true; -- Imagine this does some complicated stuff
$$ language sql stable;


create or replace function task_edit(task_report_id int) returns boolean as $$
  select report_can_edit((select * from report where id = task_report_id))
$$ language sql stable;
```

This gives
`ERROR:  subquery must return only one column`

Do I have to switch to plpgsql and select into a decared row type first? or is there a way to do this with an `sql` type function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
create or replace function task_edit(task_report_id int) 
returns boolean as $$
  select report_can_edit((select report from report where id = task_report_id))
$$ language sql stable;
```

Comment: Thank you! works a treat, surprisingly hard to find this information via google currently.